# How to replace all characters in a string using Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, replace

I am trying to replace specific characters in a Google Sheet cell using this code:

```
  var sValue = data[0][0];
  sValue = sValue .replace(" ", "");
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1); 
  cell.setValue(sValue);
```

If my text is "this is a test" I want to have "thisisatest" but the result is "thisis a test"
Only first character is replaced. How can I replace them all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Comment: Which answer would you recommend for the OPs case as there 63 answers?

Comment: @Cooper The fastest and easiest https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503209/  function C here: Regex based one.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to convert `this is a test` to `thisisatest` by replacing `" "` to `""`.

  - The value of `this is a test` is in a cell on Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

Here, I would like to propose to use TextFinder for your situation because of the following reasons.

1. In your situation, Google Spreadsheet is used.
2. In your script, the values are retrieved by `getValues` and put by `setValue`. When TextFinder is used, the search and replace process is run in the internal server. By this, the cost can be reduced.
3. TextFinder can be used for a cell, a range, a sheet and all sheets in Spreadsheet by the simple script.

#### Sample script:

From your script, it supposes the situation that the value of `this is a test` in the cell "A1" is converted to `thisisatest`.

```
const sheetName = "Sheet1";
SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName(sheetName)
  .getRange(1, 1)
  .createTextFinder(" ")
  .replaceAllWith("");
```

#### Note:

- For example, in above script, when `getRange(1, 1)` is removed like `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).createTextFinder(" ").replaceAllWith("");`, `" "` in all cells in the sheet is replaced with `""`.

#### Reference:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)